# How can I take a screenshot that includes the mouse cursor?

Tags: windows, screenshot, mouse-cursor

When taking screen shots for use in tutorials, it would be really helpful to include the mouse cursor in the picture, but I've found that most screenshot tools (including those that ship with Windows) hide the cursor from the screenshot.

How can I take a screenshot on Windows which includes the mouse cursor?

Comment: Why not just take a shot of the relevant pointer type from the control panel mouse window, and then you can paste it in where ever you like. Not an *ideal* solution, but it's probably what I'd do.

Comment: I don't know of any offhand, but I wrote a basic screenshot app, it would just be deleting a line to make it not hide the cursor, its GPL'd, so anyone can make that change freely. Source can be found here: http://www.pulsarsoftware.net/Download/Source/SC_0.1_Source.zip

Comment: @DMA57361, because I mostly need custom mouse icons which are not in the standard control panel.

Comment: @MaQleod: Sounds great, thanks - but I don't have a compiler for au3 files.

Comment: you can get a compiler for that for free here http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/downloads.shtml

Comment: **Please reopen.** There is nothing in the question that requests product, service, or learning material recommendations. The OP asks how to accomplish a particular and reasonable task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hypersnap](http://hyperionics.com/) is another good one.

Comment: The trial version adds ugly ads to the screenshot, but it worked for me so this is my answer.

Comment: Irfanview is far better, free + no ads (see next answer) -- I always copy-and-paste screenshots into Ifranview for cropping anyway, so the capture feature makes it one step.

Comment: [Solid Capture](http://www.solidcapture.com/) - ten bucks cheapier, easier to use and trial without dirt on the screenshot. (It captures mouse cursor with tooltip, in contrast to [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/))

Answer (score 68):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) has an option to include the cursor while taking screenshots. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to configure options and the hotkey.
It is [free for private, educational, and non-commercial use](http://www.irfanview.com/eula.htm).

[image: InfanView Options]

Comment: IrfanView is a great image viewer and a decent basic editor; I had no idea it took screenshots too! The screenshot capture tool looks nice and very flexible.

Comment: This should be the best answer. I've been using Irfanview for ages and completely forgot about this functionality until now.

Comment: IrfanView is good on capture, it's free and has advanced capturing options, but I couldn't get it to capture mouse cursor with tooltip..

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you very much. Did you know how to enable/disable mouse cursor using command-line options?

Comment: And how to take a screenshot?

Comment: @Black: by typing shortcut keys defined in the _Capture method -> Hot key_ section (see the screenshot).

Comment: Note: the cursor in the screenshot will lose its shadow.

Comment: Cursor appears in the wrong place!! It appears to be an ancient problem they never bothered to fix: https://irfanview-forum.de/archive/index.php/t-7694.html

Answer (score 17):

I've been very happy with Greenshot - you can turn on/off if mouse is captured or not + it has nice capability of adding notes and lines/arrows diretcly on the image after taking the shot. Great if you're creating user manuals or similar stuff.
It's also free and open source.

http://getgreenshot.org/

(I'm not in any way affiliated with this product or it's author - just a satisfied user).

Comment: As an FYI, this program does not capture the drop-shadow of the Aero mouse cursor. But it seems to do a decent job otherwise.

Comment: This is the best of them ALL! Get it on GitHub: https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/releases

Answer (score 14):

In Windows 7 you can also search 'psr' in the Start Search:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/problem-steps-recorder.htm

This produces a .mht and images you can use in a tutorial.

Comment: The only con to this method is that the images that were captured will be compressed and saved in JPEG format. Nonetheless, this helped me get my presentation across to others.

Comment: Another con to this method is that it only captures an image when you click the mouse button. In my case i was trying to record a problem that happens when you hover over the `Close` button of an application.

Comment: Exists in Windows 10 too.

Comment: Doesn't just screenshot. It adds basket balls under the cursor when it records an image.

Comment: "Records" only standard pointers, even if they are customized in fact

Comment: psr = Windows  built-in [Step Recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/record-steps-to-reproduce-a-problem-46582a9b-620f-2e36-00c9-04e25d784e47)

Answer (score 3):

ShareX is a good free tool to capture screen with cursor

Answer (score 3):

On windows 7 through 11, you can use the built in "Steps Recorder" application. This application shows the cursor as it is, and doesnt require installing a program (which may require admin access). The big disadvantage is resolution.

Unfortunately, you cannot copy the taken screenshots directly, but you can either use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to then take a screenshot of that screenshot, or use [this tutorial](https://jakeknows.tech/problem-steps-recorder-on-windows-10-11/) to extract the images.

Here are a couple of examples:

The screenshot of steps recorder that I got my target image from:
[image: A screenshot shown in steps recorder overlaid over the webpage the screenshot is of]

A couple of screenshots taken this way:

[image: screenshot with cursor]

[image: screenshot with "not allowed" cursor]

The resolution problem can be partially mitigated by enlarging the screen if the area required is small, example:

[image: screenshot with "not allowed" cursor, taken magnified for better resolution]

Answer (score 1):

[Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) has the option includes the mouse cursor. Plus it includes a REALLY good editor for screenshots. If you are **not** a computer expert, it is the best tool.

Comment: SnagIt is good and I have used both version 10 and 11. But somehow, it never captures the mouse for me on my Windows 7-64 bit machine. What's the trick there? I have used full screen, hot keys, timer but none of them work to capture the mouse cursor. I have to manually insert it by their excellent Stamp feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Screenshot Captor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/) has the option to capture the cursor. It's my screenshot tool of choice.

Comment: I’ve just checked it. It's really worth having a look at. And it shows (if wanted) the mouse pointer. (Windows 10 64 Bit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Steps Recorder**.

Press **Start Record** when you have it open, do what you have to, then press **Stop Record**.

Comment: I dont know why this was downvoted, it works well as a built in tool, even if it is slightly lower resolution

Answer (score 1):

[XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/) is another option. Go to `Tools | Capture screen...` and select `Include mouse cursor`:

[image]

> XnView is provided as FREEWARE (NO Adware, NO Spyware) for private or
> educational use (including non-profit organizations).

Answer (score 0):

[Screen Hunter](http://screenhunter-free.en.softonic.com/) should do the trick.

Comment: It does show the mouse pointer, but in a slightly misplaced location, and it messes up the background behind the mouse pointer :(

Answer (score 0):

PicPick...

http://www.picpick.org/en/

great tool -- plus has little utilities that the rest of the suggestions don't.

Comment: Please refer to this [meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) on how to give answers that may require recommending software.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of GIMP can also take screenshots with cursor. Added bonus is easy editing after the capture.

Answer (score -2):

When the mouse pointer is enlarged (large mouse pointer) on Windows 10, the only screen capture app I find can capture it is [ScreenHunter 7](https://www.wisdom-soft.com/products/screenhunter.htm). It has a free version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).