# Take screen shot on Windows that doesn't lose mouse position, similar to Mac built-in method

Tags: windows, mouse, screenshot

On my Mac I press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to take a screen shot.  At this point my "mouse" remains in the same position (which means that any hover state or webpage menu displays are preserved).  I then move my "super-cursor" as the mouse, which shows as a crosshairs, select the region I want and, presto, the screen shot appears on my desktop.

If the [Snipping Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots) is the Windows equivalent, that UX is not possible.  Are there any other ways to do this on a PC that are easy?

I have Windows 10.

Comment: This would be brilliant if Windows could do this... excellent for creating guides. Your question is likely to result in opinion-based answers as there may be different products that do what you're looking for. however, one such program that works similarly (gives a "cross-hairs" super-mouse) is ShareX (https://getsharex.com/).

Comment: Use [GreenShot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/releases) to capture mouse pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screenshot tools that include the mouse cursor?](https://superuser.com/questions/188788/screenshot-tools-that-include-the-mouse-cursor)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate - I don't want to capture the mouse position - but I do want to capture what the mouse has done by its _current_ position like menu appearance and focus and hover colors, etc. - this is destroyed if I have to move the mouse to get to another program (and even if I didn't, Mac does it best with just `Command-Shift-4`)

Comment: I use GreenShot. It will do what you are talking about.